# Is any ARM platform emulation in qemu functional enough to run ARM v7 code in multicore emulation mode?

Tags: qemu, armv7

It seems like qemu ( atleast version 2.0.0 ) have issues with running U-boot and distros of Linux on ARMv7 boards in in case of vexpress-a9 and vespress-a15. Have anyone here succeeded runing multicore ARMv7 Operating System? If yes what was qemu release version? 
I mean run with

```
qemu -M someplatform -cpu cores=2 ...
```

Comment: Issues I wrote about are discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068688/have-you-got-issues-with-running-u-boot-for-versatile-express-a9-platform-under

Comment: "QEMU seems to be broken" is more of a bug report for the QEMU mailing list, than an on-topic programming question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That too, but also its sometimes possible to fix things by applying patches or cherrypicking commits from gitrepo, which is some kind of programming. ;)

Answer (score 3):

**`qemu-system-arm -M virt -cpu cortex-a15`**

This setup worked just fine:

```
qemu-system-arm \
-M virt \
-append 'root=/dev/vda' \
-cpu cortex-a15 \
-drive file='rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2' \
-kernel zImage \
-nographic \
-smp '2'
```

Then:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

gives:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 125.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc0f
CPU revision    : 1

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 125.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc0f
CPU revision    : 1
```

I also bet it would work with `-M vexpress-a15 -cpu cortex-a15` but I didn't test that. If you want to try it out, just copy exactly [what Buildroot says](https://github.com/rancher/buildroot/tree/e5f64bed430005e502c6419317f1354728070e42/board/qemu/arm-vexpress), and it will work as usual.

Tested in QEMU 2.11.0, Linux v2.16, with [this setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/36cffd5c1a6e081194610d1d77a43a863f1d1157).